# Need some help to add addEventListener for keyup, when i press 'Enter' button

Tags: javascript

```
function animatedForm() {

  const arrows = document.querySelectorAll(".fa-arrow-down");

  arrows.forEach(arrow => {

    arrow.addEventListener("click", () => {

      const input = arrow.previousElementSibling;
      const parent = arrow.parentElement;
      const nextForm = parent.nextElementSibling;

      //Validation

      if (input.type === "text" && validateUser(input)) {
        nextStep(parent, nextForm);
      } else if (input.type === "email" && validateEmail(input)) {
        nextStep(parent, nextForm);
      } else if (input.type === "password" && validatePassword(input)) {
        nextStep(parent, nextForm);
      } 


    });

  });

};

function nextStep(parent, nextForm) {

  parent.classList.add("inactive");  
parent.classList.remove("active");  
nextForm.classList.add("active"); }



function error(color) {

  document.body.style.background = color; }



animatedForm();
```

Comment: Take at least 5 minutes of your time to write a proper question so people here get motivated to take the time for solving your issue

Answer (score 0):

To add enter key up event, all you have to do is add a keyup listener and filter on which key was pressed like this :

```
element.addEventListener('keyup', e => {
    // e.key might not be supported, keyCode for backward compatibility
    if(e.key && e.key !== "Enter" || e.keyCode !== 13) return
    // your code here
}
```

Comment: MDN says "which" property in keyboardEvent is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run some code when enter button pressed, listen to 'keydown' event on document element and check event.key in listener. Your code should be something like that:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
   if(e.key === 'Enter') doSomething();
})
```